# Как изменить почту рассылки Postfix

Tags: php, vps, postfix

Есть VPS с установленным сервисом рассылки Postfix. Как на нем поменять адрес рассылки? Сейчас например стоит site@mail.com  а нужно admin@mail.com. Рассылку делаю через PHP, в настройках php.ini есть строчка sendmail_path, но в ней ничего не задано, значит адрес задается где-то в другом месте?

Answer (score 1):

Адрес задается где-то в PHP коде.